# C++ HTTP chunked gzip: портится gzip поток

Tags: c, http, c++

Всем привет!

При получении каждой *дцатой страницы портится gzip поток, причем всегда в разное время, не могу поймать момент, когда он портится, ну чтоб узнать из-за чего да почему:)
Помогите! http client первый раз делаю, может тут явная где-то ошибка ?!

```
//Раньше тут было много быдлокода
```

p.s. функции ParseHeaders, GetDataId, GetBlockSize точно работаю правильно...

-----Добавленно 14,06,12

Переписал вот так, и получилось много рабочего *быдлокода*:)
Запостил сюда этот *быдлокода* только по тому что лично я так и не нашел 
пример реализации HTTP клиента с поддержкой chunked и gzip

```
inline int ::Recessive(char* chRecessiveBuffer) 
{
    int result, len = 0;
    DWORD dwBlockSize = 0;
    bool bHeadersReceived = false, chunked = false; 
    char* buffer = new char[dwRecvBufferLen+1];

    while((result = recv(sSocket, buffer, dwRecvBufferLen, 0)) != SOCKET_ERROR)
    {
        if (result == 0) break;                         //Cоединение закрыто!!!
        char* chBlock = &buffer[0];

        if (!bHeadersReceived)
        {
            //ParseHeaders подвигает за сабой положение chBlock и result 
            //bool HTTPHeaders::ParseHeaders (char*&, int&);
            if (bHeadersReceived = Headers->ParseHeaders(chBlock, result))
            {   //Если получили заголовки
                //определяем это chunked или нет
                Headers->GetTransferParam(dwBlockSize, chunked);

                //Если код ответа не имеет контента
                if (Headers->Code == 0 || (Headers->Code >= 100 && Headers->Code < 200) ||
                    Headers->Code == 204 || Headers->Code == 304) break;

                if (!chunked) { //Content-Length
                    if (dwBlockSize == 0) break;   //или пустой, выходим
                    len += dwBlockSize;
                }

            } else continue;    //Если получили не все заголовки, получаем еще блок
        }

        while (result--)
        {
            if (dwBlockSize == 0)               //Если конец блока
            if (chunked)                        //Проверяем если это chunked
            {
                if (result < 2) break;  //4 = \r\n0\r\n ~ result--

                dwBlockSize = GetBlockSize(chBlock, result);//Получаем размер следующего блока
                if (!dwBlockSize) {
                    chunked = false;
                    break;
                }
                len += dwBlockSize;
                if (result <= 0) break;

            }else
                break; //Если не chunked значит content-length, все получили и выходим

            *chRecessiveBuffer++ = *chBlock++;
            dwBlockSize--;
        }

        if (result < 0) result = 0; 
        if (!chunked && dwBlockSize == 0) break;
    }

    delete[] buffer;
    *chRecessiveBuffer = 0;

    if (result == SOCKET_ERROR) {
        result = WSAGetLastError();
        if (result == 10053 || result == 10054) {
            return -2;
        }
        Log->ErrorFromCode(result);
        if (result != 10014) {
            MYCLOSESOCK(sSocket);
            return -1;
        }
    }
    return len;
}

inline long ::GetBlockSize(char*& rec, int &i)
{
    int len = 0;

    do {
        if (*rec == '\r') {
            if (len) {
                *rec = 0;
                break;
            } else {
                rec += 2;
                i -= 2;
            }
        }
        len++;
    }
    while (*rec++);

    rec -= len;
    long l = strtol(rec, 0, 16);
    rec += len + 2;
    i -= (len + 2);
    return l;
}

inline bool ::UnzipText(const void* src, int srcLen, char* dest, int destLen)
{
    dest[0] = 0;
    int err;
    z_stream strm;

    strm.avail_in = (UINT)srcLen;
    strm.next_in = (Bytef*)src;
    strm.zalloc = (alloc_func)0;
    strm.zfree = (free_func)0;

    if(inflateInit2(&strm, 16 + MAX_WBITS) != Z_OK) {
        Log->Str("zlib inflateInit error!");
        return false;
    }

    DWORD dwBufSize = 4096;
    Bytef* out = new Bytef[dwBufSize+1];
    do
    {
        strm.avail_out = dwBufSize;
        strm.next_out = out;
        err = inflate(&strm, Z_NO_FLUSH);

        if (strm.avail_out < dwBufSize) {
            out[dwBufSize-strm.avail_out]=0;
            strcat(dest, (char*)out);
        }

        if (err != Z_OK) break;
    } while ( 1 );

    delete[] out;

    if (err != Z_STREAM_END) {
        switch (err) {
            case Z_STREAM_ERROR: Log->Str("Z_STREAM_ERROR"); break;
            case Z_DATA_ERROR: Log->Str("Z_DATA_ERROR"); break;
            case Z_MEM_ERROR: Log->Str("Z_MEM_ERROR"); break;
            case Z_BUF_ERROR: Log->Str("Z_BUF_ERROR"); break;
        default: Log->Str("Unidentified error!");
        }
    }
    err = inflateEnd(&strm);
    if(strm.total_out) {
        dest[strm.total_out]=0;
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Огромное спасибо за комментарии!

Comment: подозреваю, что имеет место выход за пределы массива. Вот к примеру один подозрительный момент `if (buffer[i+2] == 0 || buffer[i+1] == 0 || (i >= result-2))`. Его явно лучше переписать так `if ((i >= result-2) || (buffer[i+2] == 0) || (buffer[i+1] == 0))`.

Comment: а есть какая то вселенская разница между buffer[i+1] == 0 и (buffer[i+1] == 0) ? я не знаю просто...

Comment: Наверняка где то за пределы выходит, ведь кажется крайне мало вероятным что сервер отдает порченные данные=) просто это происходит всегда на разных страницах и с ..~разного раза

Comment: @lirik90, Вы уверены, что "порченая" страница тоже chunked ? Может в ее заголовках вместо "Transfer-Encoding" есть "Content-Length" ? 

IMHO Вы http заголовки весьма небрежно разбираете.

Comment: >> а есть какая то вселенская разница между buffer[i+1] == 0 и (buffer[i+1] == 0) ? я не знаю просто...

Просто читаемость. Компилятору побоку, а человеку приятно. Но это дело вкуса.

Comment: @lirik90, посмотрел повнимательней. Если в первом же recv() все заголовки **не будут прочитаны**, то работать эта программа не будет. 

Остаток, читаемый следующим в цикле recv() будет копироваться в recessive, а это еще не gzip.

Понятно ? 

Вы предполагаете что **как минимум заголовки** будут прочитаны первым recv(), но это никто не гарантирует.

Comment: Серьезно?!:) меня просто кто-то где-то в каких-то закромах интернета надоумил что мол... да неважно, да и правда чего это я)) сейчас перепишу проверю, спасибо, но все равно предчувствие что проблема в другом IMHO=))

Comment: ...да я уверен, точно chunked и точно gzip

Comment: @lirik90, Вы для отладки весь протокол (и отметки **recv**) в какой-нибудь, лог-файл складывайте.

Comment: @lirik90, переписали чтение заголовков? Получилось?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[@lirik90](/users/7607/lirik90), IMHO ошибочки остались.

1). Вы пишете

```
        strcat(recessive, buffer);
        len = strlen(recessive);
```

но recv() **не заносит** 0 в конец прочитанных данных. Правльно будет:

```
memcpy(recessive+len,buffer,result);
len += result;
recessive[len] = buffer[result] = 0; // это если надо будет с ними, как со строками
```

2) По RFC 2661 (Hypertext Transfer Protocol -- HTTP/1.1) "transfer-encoding" и "content-length" **могут** одновременно присутствовать в заголовках. В этом случае "content-length" следует игнорировать.

3) Надо все-таки делать проверки на переполнение массивов и (возможно), что сервер шлет именно текст (без двоичных нулей). Не знаю, возможны они (нули) в *правильном* передаваемом gzip или нет, но в **хорошей** программе такие проверки и какая-то реакция на них нужна. Кстати, используя строковые функции с buffer и recessive, Вы подразумеваете, что нулей там нет, иначе работать будет неправильно.

Comment: 1. И правда не заметил, спасибо, перед strcat(recessive, buffer); вставил еще buffer[result]=0;
2. Еще раз спасибо, не знал) 
3. А вот этот пункт что то я не понял)) 
строковые функции в смысле strcat ?! так заголовки передаются в любом случае текстом, и strcat используется только при получении заголовков из расчета того что с первым recv все заголовки не получились! а в gzip там чуть ли не каждый второй 0 )) когда получаем данные заносим в recessive их просто циклом (без строковых функций) или я не так что то понял ?
Спасибо!

Comment: По поводу 3) это я не заметил, что Вы в цикле переписываете все из буфера (после заголовков). 

Про 1) memcpy() в случае передачи заголовков несколькими блоками эффективнее strcat(), а текущая длина у Вас все равно есть. Хотя, на  работоспособность программы не повлияет.